# converting to an ellipse equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, education

I have the following question:
\begin{equation}
z\:=\:x^2+y^2+xy-x+y+1
\end{equation}

after I complete the square, I end up with this
\begin{equation}
z\:=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+xy+\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
however this doesn't look like the generic equation of an ellipse below by any means:
\begin{equation}
z\:=\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2
\end{equation}

can anybody please help! much appreciated in advance.

Comment: https://www.sparknotes.com/math/precalc/conicsections/section5/#:~:text=To%20eliminate%20the%20xy%20term,that%20cot(2%CE%B8)%20%3D%20.

Comment: I don't see any question: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the $xy$ term, then you must make a change of coordinates: $$x={x'+y'\over\sqrt2},\quad y={x'-y'\over\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$z=\left(x+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}(y+1)^2$$

Comment: Can you please show how you arrived at this? Was there a some kind of substitution needed?

Comment: @Raykh The expression $\left(x+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ takes any addends with  $x$ and the rest you saw.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able apply your comment through and arrived at your answer. Thank you very much again

Comment: @Raykh You are welcome!